# regex find numbers with hyphens between html tag in notepad++

Tags: regex, between

I have html tags like bellow

```
<id>1234-12</id>
<id>12345-123</id>
<id>123</id>
<id>12345</id>
<id>12346</id>

I want to find all numbers between <id> </id> that has hyphens
exampple 

<id>1234-12</id>
<id>12345-123</id>
```

this will find all between  tag

```
<id>.+?<\/id>
```

but how to find only numbers with hyphens
Thanks!

Comment: `<id>\d+-\d+<\/id>` ?

Comment: Or only numbers `<id>\K\d+-\d+(?=<\/id>)` https://regex101.com/r/iHFidZ/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find only numbers with a hyphen in between:

```
<id>\K\d+-\d+(?=<\/id>
```

**Explanation**

- `<id>` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d+-\d+` Match `-` surrounded by 1+ digits
- `(?=<\/id>` Assert `</id>` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iHFidZ/1)